# Does the limit rule $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ apply to $\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\sin\left(x-\pi\right)}{\left(x-\pi\right)}=1$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

In my textbook, I was given an example below :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\sin\left(x-\pi\right)}{\left(x-\pi\right)}=1$$

Previously I was taught that this formula :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$

only applies when $x$ approaches $0$. Can someone explain to me?

Comment: It is essentially the same, you get from the first to the second by substituting $x-\pi$ by $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y=x-\pi$. Then $y$ approaches $0$ if and only if $x$ approaches $\pi$. So we may write the following

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\sin\left(x-\pi\right)}{\left(x-\pi\right)}=\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1$$

EDIT: One may also see it as a [composition of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions).

Comment: In other words, $\pi$ has nothing to do with it. You might as well take the limit of $\frac{\sin(x-a)}{x-a}$ as $x\to a$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course and more in general for any $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to x_0\in \mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm \infty\}$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}\frac{\sin\left(f(x)\right)}{f(x)}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hospital's rule to verify:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\sin\left(x-\pi\right)}{\left(x-\pi\right)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{\cos\left(x-\pi\right)}{1}=\cos0=1.$$